# Why netgear can't be used on debian?

Tags: networking

I have installed dual system on my pc,one is win7 ,the other is debian8.
Here is my net structure:adsl modem+netgear wndr 3800CH+pc.
It is so strange that same hardware environment for dual system ,the network is in good status when to enter into win7,but in bad status when to enter into debian8.
Let us start from win7.
[image]
Now reboot to enter into debian8.
[image]

```
root@hws:/home/debian8# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:57:4b:d1  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fe57:4bd1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42450 (41.4 KiB)  TX bytes:12533 (12.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15994 (15.6 KiB)  TX bytes:15994 (15.6 KiB)


cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

In order to fix it :
1.I login into my netgear administrater gui ,and change the gateway from 192.168.0.1 into 192.168.1.1
2.vim /etc/network/interfaces
change from

```
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

into

```
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

reboot into debian, only two ip can be visited 192.168.1.1 and `192.168.1.100', all the public ips can not be visited, reboot into win7, all the public ips can be visited,how to fix now?
I have done as Big Chris say .
The local pc ip can't be set as 192.168.1.100,it was set as 192.168.1.2 by dhcp.
How to set local pc ip as  192.168.1.100 ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's anything wrong with debian. Your system is reconfigured by the look of things. Your address is on the 192.168.1.x subnet, while the rest of your network is on the 192.168.0.x subnet. Fix that, restart networking and see what happens.

Comment: My local pc is 192.168.1.100,the gateway is 192.168.0.1,let me change the gateway into 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Nooo... change the local PC, not the gateway. You'll break less things that way.

Comment: no ,all the guid in my wordpress are all in the form of 192.168.1.100,my wordpres was built on 192.168.1.100.

Comment: Make sure that's the issue *first* before risking knocking out your entire network.

Comment: I  login into my netgear administrater gui ,and change the gateway from 192.168.0.1 into 192.168.1.1,reboot  into debian, only two ip can be visited `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.100', all the public ips can not be visited, reboot into win7, all the public ips can  be visited,how to fix now?

Comment: I donno. I gave a clear example of what the problem is, and the *best* way to check if that's an issue. If you do the exact opposite of what I suggested, I really have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Your gateway is still wrong. Your gateway must match your router IP.

Comment: How to get my router IP with some commands?

Comment: Probably because the ip address range hasn't been changed? gateway hadn't been changed? I donno. I suggested a single line change... and well... I'm pretty sure you can move wordpress between ip addresses (I've done that once? Maybe twice? Granted on the same domain). Not to mention its not really in the question. I'm a little grumpier than I should be so I'll revisit this in the morning.

Comment: Why on earth did you mess with the Debian settings of default DHCP enabled to get an IP automatically??? You then wouldn't have any problem at all...

Comment: all the guid in my wordpress are all in the form of 192.168.1.100.I can make  eth0 be  static  in /etc/network/interfaces.My local pc should be set as 192.168.1.100.Why win7 works fine ,not debina8 for the same router configuration?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Both router/gateway and your computer/OS have to be configured properly. Windows uses default config, Debian uses your broken manual config. Stop messing with router settings, configure Debian properly.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to reset your eth0 back to DHCP:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Your Debian will then be able to get a working IP from your router and you'll be able to get to your router admin pages as desired.

Regarding your WordPress GUIDs: In hindsight you should have created a virtual host or hosts file entry to a test domain name rather than a server IP address. Additionally, there are WordPress tools that can bulk modify the server name of your site. WordPress have thought of all of this and there are tutorials on how to change your server and site address.

Comment: I have tested as you say, only one problem remain,the local pc can't be set as 192.168.1.100,it was set as 192.168.1.2 by dhcp.

Comment: Your router DHCP server is providing addresses from 192.168.0.x so leave it at that. Are you just trying to set your local PC to 192.168.1.100 for your WordPress site? If so, get the DB fixed and look into a name based solution, rather than an IP fix as the next time your IP changes you'll have the same problem... ideally you should look at hosting for your site so that you can point the browser to the domain name rather than an IP... OR: decide on an IP range and if you change your router reconfigure it to change the range of IPs it hands out to devices to match your WP site.

Answer (score 0):

Problems sovled.
In netgear admin gui,nameserver is set to be  221.11.132.2\221.11.132.3
But in my /etc/resolv.conf,nameserver is 192.168.1.1

```
vim /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver  221.11.132.2
nameserver  221.11.132.3
```

ALL problems solved.